# Ant: p4sync fileset

Tags: java, ant, synchronization, perforce

I have a fileset containing a bunch of .jar files that I need to force sync.
However, the p4sync task takes a view as an argument, so I am not sure how to pass it the files in the fileset.

Note, I am able to do this:

```
<p4sync view="./lib/mod/hello-*" force="true"/>
```

But this fails:

```
<p4sync force="true">
   <fileset refid="lib.mod.hello"/>
<p4sync/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your fileset into a string property using the `<pathconvert>` task, and then use that property as your view value in your `<p4sync>` task, something like:

```
<fileset id="files" dir=".">
    <include name="file1"/>
    <include name="file2"/>
</fileset>
<pathconvert refid="files" pathsep=" " property="view"/>
<p4sync view="${view}" force="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this was possible before.